# Django application behaves strangely, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: python, django

We are building a school information system using Python/Django. The production server runs Ubuntu, Apache2 with mod_wsgi. Recently strange things happen to our server. When we test our code locally everything works well. After deployment the application works, but sometimes returns 'Page not found' or 'Division by zero' errors. Why is this happen, from attack or server configuration, please help us!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308335/how-to-handle-the-divide-by-zero-exception-in-list-comprehensions-while-dividing

Answer (score 0):

- Is server running out of memory or disk errors? Do *dmesg*, and verify for any exceptions or errors reported.
- System is compromised? check for */var/log/auth.log*
- Secure SSH using non standard port or by installing [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/)
- Scan through *syslog* for any other error
- If any logging is enabled in django, check for errors.
- Apache logs in */var/log/apache2* can give details of access details and any errors.

If none of above, please provide more details like configurations/logs from Apache, Syslog.